# Fastest PostgreSQL query for field length?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

If I need to find the maximum length of a few fields stored as numeric (i.e. variable length number) in postgresql so my team can build a fixed width file layout and the length isn't in the metadata, is there a faster way to get that info than either

```
select field 
from table 
where field is not null 
order by field desc 
limit 1;
```

or

```
select max(field) 
from table;
```

?

The tables these fields are in have tens of millions of rows so these queries are taking quite a while. I'm a decent postgresql user, but optimizing for efficiency has never been my strong suite - I don't usually work with such large datasets. Any help is appreciated, even if this is a dumb question!

Comment: You should check the execution plans of both queries, and you might even find they are the same.  The second version is what you would probably use in a production system.

Comment: Why must it be fast? What should happen if there are *only* NULL values?

Comment: Why not just allocate, say, 10 digits to an integer.  That is sufficient.  I'm not sure that saving a few bytes in the files is worth the effort.

Comment: It's more just a time constraint concern at this point - these are ad-hoc queries to help populate a fixed width file layout, and with the number of rows in the tables, some of the queries are taking 30+ minutes. We're hoping to turn the file layout around within the next day or two.

Comment: @GordonLinoff we have a max byte width on the fixed width file, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries look fine. The `where` clause is not needed in the first query, that can be written as:

```
select myfield from mytable order by myfield desc nulls last limit 1;
```

Then, for performance, consider the following index:

```
create index myidx on mytable(myfield desc nulls last);
```

Actually Postgres should be able to read the index backwards, so this should be just as good:

```
create index myidx on mytable(myfield);
```

With any of these indexes in place, the database should be able to execute the whole query by looking at the index only, which should be very efficient.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is asking which of the 2 queries would be most performant.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the way I read the question is: is there a faster way than the two given queries? Which is what the first sentence of my answer attempts to answer.